# Failed to running a container with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have got an error while executing the following shell on my ubuntu vbox.

```
docker-compose up -d
```

```
Step 1/4 : FROM postgres:9.4
 ---> d1b08fdd94ed
Step 2/4 : RUN mkdir /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/census/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 35c38c9966fb
Step 3/4 : COPY ./sql/census/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/census
ERROR: Service 'db' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder974990962/sql/census: no such file or directory
```

I searched on google but didn't get a tip to fix this problem.

Could you help me with this?

Thanks for your attention.
Best regards,
Liki

### Folder structure

```
docker-compose.yml
db/Dockerfile
web/Dockerfile
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/web/Dockerfile
    container_name: wazimap-vpuu
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:postgres@db/postgres
    expose:
      - "8000"
    command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate --noinput && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/vpuu
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/db/Dockerfile
    container_name: wazimap-postgres
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

### db/Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:9.4

RUN mkdir /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/census/
COPY sql/census/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/census
COPY sql/extensions/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

### web/Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt install -y gdal-bin libgdal-dev
RUN apt install -y python-pip git

ENV CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH /usr/include/gdal
ENV C_INCLUDE_PATH /usr/include/gdal

RUN mkdir /vpuu
WORKDIR /vpuu

COPY . /vpuu

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but I do not see the error message on your post. I just see steps 1 thru 3 (out of 4) in the build process. Is the error message after that? Also does the docker file for Postgres build properly by itself? (without docker-compose)

Comment: Step 1/4 : FROM postgres:9.4
 ---> d1b08fdd94ed
Step 2/4 : RUN mkdir /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/census/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 35c38c9966fb
```Step 3/4 : COPY ./sql/census/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/census
ERROR: Service 'db' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder974990962/sql/census: no such file or directory```

Comment: Hi Camba1, I missed writing a full error message. Sorry for that.

Comment: Hi Camba1, docker build for Postgres also failed. Same error.

Comment: Where is the `census` directory in your local source tree?  (The files there will need to be copied directly into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`, not a subdirectory.)

Comment: @LikiCrus where in the host file system are files `sql/census/` and `sql/extensions/` ? Try to put them in building context

Comment: Hi Camba1, Yasen, David, thanks for your attention. I sorted out this issue. I didn't have any files under the [src] folder. That's sql/census folder was empty. So I created it and put some sql files there. Finally, docker-compose worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

> The `COPY` instruction copies new files or directories from `<src>` and adds them to the filesystem of the container at the path `<dest>`.

`<src>` is specified in context in the docker-compose dockerfile directive

Error `COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder974990962/sql/census: no such file or directory` means that file `sql/census` not found in building context.

To `COPY` something, you should put it in building context before that.

Comment: Hi Yasen, thanks for your reply. But I don't know how to add sql/census in buildin context. I set it up as "context: ." in docker-compose.yml. Could you advise on this please?

Comment: Do you need these files? Do you know what are they mean for the app?

Comment: Hi Yasen, I fixed. I didn't miss to put census folder under sql folder.

Comment: Thanks, Yasen. I sorted out this. I added my comment on the main post.